# 8 Channel RS232 relay board from china

Tags: serial-port, hardware, serial-communication, relaycommand

So I purchased this device from a company in china thinking, I'm savvy, I'll be able to figure it out.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/RS232-DC-12V-8Ch-Serial-control-computer-control-switch-Relay-Board-Module-/261695306230?hash=item3cee4179f6:g:UVwAAOSwWnFWBPYq

Well now that I have it, I can not figure out RS232 commands to issue and I can not find a manual anywhere.  I've tried looking at similar devices and issuing commands like "FF 01 01" which equates to "addressofboard, relay, state" in other similar devices.  Can anyone help me find a manual or has anyone ever used this thing?

Comment: The very short description for this board says that each data frame contains 8 bytes. Try to send something like 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a reply from the manufacturer.  It's so complicated that I would have never guess the correct order.  Here are the commands:

Close 1 channel：56 01 13 00 00 01 01 6C 
Open 1 channel ：56 01 13 00 00 01 00 6B

Close 2 channel：56 01 13 00 00 02 02 6E 
Open 2  channel：56 01 13 00 00 02 00 6C

Close 3 channel：56 01 13 00 00 04 04 72
Open 3  channel：56 01 13 00 00 04 00 6E

Close 4 channel：56 01 13 00 00 08 08 7A
Open 4  channel：56 01 13 00 00 08 00 72

Close 5 channel：56 01 13 00 00 10 10 8A 
Open 5  channel：56 01 13 00 00 10 00 7A

Close 6 channel：56 01 13 00 00 20 20 AA 
Open 6  channel：56 01 13 00 00 20 00 8A

Close 7 channel：56 01 13 00 00 40 40 EA 
Open 7  channel：56 01 13 00 00 40 00 AA

Close 7 channel：56 01 13 00 00 80 80 6A
Open 7  channel：56 01 13 00 00 80 00 EA

The structure is weird to me but I'm sure it makes sense somewhere:

(data, device address, function, empty, empty, relay, state, checksum)

The checksum is an addition of all the values and taking the 8th value of that addition.